# Get parent node id of DOM after HTML5 drag & drop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a page in which you can drag widgets from one div a to div b. I want to assign the id of the recipient div to a variable. my events are set up like this:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var parentId;
    parentId = data.parentNode.id;
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Try `ev.toElement.parentNode.id`. If that doesn't work, you are going to have to provide more information. Relevant HTML work be nice. A live example would be even better.

Comment: my solution of parentId = data.parentNode.id doesnt seem to be working

Comment: `ev` refers to the element where the item is dropped. I myself use a temporary global to do this and delete it after the drop.

Comment: i ended up solving this myself. here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qbhbkps/34/